# How do you convert form values into an array in VUE

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to figure out how to convert `info` into an array to compare it with another array.

This is my code

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="info.q1">
<input type="checkbox" v-model="info.q2">
<input type="checkbox" v-model="info.q3">

Answers[],    
info : {
      q1: '4',
      q2: '4',
      q3: '4'
    }
```

I'm trying to get something like the below:

```
var answers = [{q1: 4},{q2: 4}]
```

Comment: Mention what format of array you want .

Comment: `this.Answers = Object.values(this.info)`? See [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a `Computed Property` with the name `answers` like:

```
    answers () {
        return Object.entries(this.info).map( ([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }) )
    }
```

After creating `computed property` you can call it like `this.answers`.

or

You can make make in method like:

```
    methodName(){
        const answers = Object.entries(this.info).map( ([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }) )
    }
```

Comment: Don't make it a method if you can make it a computed property. Computed properties are cached and automatically updated when the data it depends on changes. There is no reason in this example to use a method.

Answer (score 1):

Make a computed property that calculates `answers` based on `info`.

```
computed: {
  answers () {
    return Object.entries(this.info).map(
      ([key, value]) => { [key]: value }
    )
  }
}
```